# Does this poset property have a name?

Tags: terminology, order-theory

I have a poset with the following property:

> For any infinite descending chain $x_1 > x_2 > \dots$ and any $y$ that is a lower bound for the chain ($y < x_i$ for all indices $i$), there exists $y' > y$ that is also a lower bound for the chain.

Does this property have a standard name, or is it equivalent or related to a property with a name?